# TestFlight 1.2 SDK installation instructions for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, installation, testflight

I'm about to install the TestFlight 1.2 SDK for iOS but I'm a little confused on how to go about it. I remember in the past you needed to create an "Ad-hoc provisioning profile" but reading the [installation notes](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/doc/1.2/) for TestFlight 1.2 there is no mentioning of this anymore. Also I remember that there were instructions that you needed to create a new scheme for Xcode but there is also no mentioning of it anymore (at least now what I can find). I currently just have a "Debug" and "Release" scheme.

Should I create an "Ad-hoc provisioning profile"? Should I create a new scheme? Or should I just follow the installation notes?

Comment: Are you trying to use the TestFlight SDK or use TestFlight to distribute your app to testers? They are independent features that complement each other. If you are just trying to do the second, here are the instructions: http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829857

Comment: @jasongregori I'm interested in knowing about how to deal with provisioning profiles and Xcode schemes for Testflight...

Comment: TestFlight doesn't require anything special to do with provisioning profiles and Xcode schemes. You use the same provisioning profiles and schemes that you would use to run your app on an actual device. The only difference is that you archive the build and upload it to TestFlight instead of just running it on your device.

Comment: If you need help getting to that point, this is a great reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/00-About_the_iOS_Application_Development_Workflow/introduction.html